# SQL Server - OPTION OPTIMIZE FOR - 2 specific IDs

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm creating a stored procedure that queries a lot of data but the query is specific to 2 customers in one country.

I'm just wondering if it's possible to add multiple CustomerIDs to an OPTIMIZE FOR statement e.g.

```
option (OPTIMIZE FOR (@CountryId = 122, @CustomerId = 321654, @CustomerId 78954))
```

The above example doesn't compile:

A compile-time literal value is specified more than once for the variable "@CustomerId" in one or more OPTIMIZE FOR clauses.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is call a different procedure depending on the parameter value and each procedure will calculate its own statistics, e.g. in your procedure IF @CustomerId = 321654 EXEC proc_321654 ELSE EXEC proc_78954. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE innerProc_78954
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    WHERE CustomerId = 78954
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE innerProc_321654
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    WHERE CustomerId = 321654
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE outerProc
@CustomerId INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @CustomerId = 321654
        EXEC innerProc_321654
    ELSE
        EXEC innerProc_78954
END
GO
```

So innerProc_78954 and innerProc_321654 are basically duplicates, but each is only ever called with a specific parameter, and thus each has statistics optimized for its own parameter.

Here's a simple example with sample data to demonstrate:

```
-- Create test data - 10,000 rows for CustomerId 1, 100 rows for CustomerId 2

CREATE TABLE #Orders (CustomerId INT, OrderDate DATETIME)
DECLARE @c1 INT = 0
DECLARE @c2 INT = 0
WHILE @c1 < 100
BEGIN
    SET @c2 = 0
    WHILE @c2 < 100
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerId, OrderDate) VALUES (1, GETDATE() - 100)
        SET @c2 += 1
    END
    INSERT INTO #Orders (CustomerId, OrderDate) VALUES (2, GETDATE() - 100)
    SET @c1 += 1
END
GO

-- The procedure optimized for CustomerId = 1

CREATE PROCEDURE #proc1
@CustomerId INT
AS
    SELECT * FROM #Orders WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
GO

-- The procedure optimized for CustomerId = 2

CREATE PROCEDURE #proc2
@CustomerId INT
AS
    SELECT * FROM #Orders WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
GO

-- The outer procedure to call from your client application.

CREATE PROCEDURE #procAll
@CustomerId INT
AS
    IF @CustomerId = 1
        EXEC #proc1 1
    ELSE
        EXEC #proc2 2
GO

-- Run your outer procedure and verify the actual # of rows matches the 
-- estimated # of rows for each parameter.

EXEC #procAll 1
EXEC #procAll 2

-- Now run the inner procedures with the incorrect parameters - note that the 
-- estimated # of rows does not match the actual # of rows, demonstrating that
-- statistics were optimized for the other parameter. 

EXEC #proc1 2
EXEC #proc2 1
```